# If event does not contain another event, make the event nan [pandas]

Tags: pandas

I have a binary event, let's say the column is `[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]`

I also have two other columns that represent other events.

```
[False, True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, True, False, False, False]
[False, False, False, True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False]
```

So the full dataframe would look like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
                   'b': [False, True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, True, False, False, False]
                   'c': [False, False, False, True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False]})
```

What i want to do with the first column, is make an entire event group nan, if the neither of corresponding columns contain at least one True for any index of this group, and leave the entire event group as is otherwise.

So the output column should be `[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 1, 1, 1, 1, np.nan, np.nan]`

Comment: `df[0].where(df[[1,2]].any(1))
`?

Comment: Doesn't look like this gives the output i need. It does the check element wise, whereas i need the entire group to be nan or left alone based on whether or not any element of the group is True.

Comment: Why is the fifth value `nan`, but not the first? Both have two `false` values.

Comment: @AlanaO'Neill the confusion comes from you not providing an actual dataframe.  YOBEN had to guess at your column names because you didn't provide them.  Also, if they did get your column names correct, you may not realize that you need to assign the results back to the dataframe.  Try `df.iloc[:, 0].where(df.iloc[:, [1, 2]].any(1), inplace=True)`

Comment: edited for clarity